# Distribution of $N$ balls numbered from $1$ to $N$ without replacement

Tags: probability-distributions

Same question as  "Distribution of $N$ balls numbered $1$ to $N$ with replacement", but without
replacement:

An urn contains $N$ balls numbered $1,2,3,...,N$.

I draw at random $n$ balls, one by one WITHOUT replacement.

Let $X$ the smallest number, the largest $Y$ and $S$ the sum of all the $n$ numbers

How to compute:

- the probability $P(X=x,Y=y)$  that $X=x$ AND $Y=y$
- the probability that $S=s$

Comment: perhaps you'd better  merge these questions

Comment: @LeilaHatami And yet another useless edit to a 6 years old question. Well done.

Comment: @Did Sure you cannot find more productive ways of contributing to the site?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the distribution of $(X,Y)$. The event $[x\le X,Y\le y]$ corresponds to subsets of size $n$ drawn from the set $[x,y]$ of size $y-x+1$. There are $\displaystyle{y-x+1\choose n}$ such subsets hence
$$
P(x\le X,Y\le y)=c{y-x+1\choose n},\qquad \frac1c={N\choose n}.
$$
Decomposing the event $[X=x,Y=y]$ thanks to the events $[x\le X,Y\le y]$, $[x\le X,Y\le y-1]$, $[x+1\le X,Y\le y]$ and $[x+1\le X,Y\le y-1]$, one gets
$$
P(X=x,Y=y)=c{y-x+1\choose n}-2c{y-x\choose n}+c{y-x-1\choose n},
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
P(X=x,Y=y)=c{y-x-1\choose n-2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you Didier. What about the second question (probability that S=s) ?